# What is this olympic icon in the iPhone status bar?

Tags: iphone

Today, professional skier Tom Wallisch (at one point on the US Ski team) uploaded a screenshot of his phone:

[image: tom wallisch olympic icon]
<sub>(source: [newschoolers.com](http://thumbs.newschoolers.com/index.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fmedia.newschoolers.com%2Fuploads%2Fimages%2F17%2F00%2F73%2F51%2F82%2F735182.png&size=400x1000))</sub>

Does the Olympic icon indicate this is an Olympic, or US Olympic, sanctioned iPhone? Are there other examples of custom brand icons in the status bar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the iOS carrier name/logo is possible using external tools on your mac or on the iPhone, if the iPhone is jailbroken. There is no indication that this iPhone is related to the olympics at all. Changing the carrier logo is relatively easy.

To change the carrier to a logo using a mac on a non jailbroken iPhone, use the following tool: http://uhelios.com/downloads/.

To change the carrier on a jailbroken phone, use the tool Zeppelin. A how to can be found here: http://www.iphonehacks.com/2013/12/change-iphone-carrier-logo-ios-7-zeppelin.html.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a jailbroken iPhone which has had a tweak installed (such as [the Zeppelin tweak for iOS7](http://www.redmondpie.com/change-ios-7-carrier-logo-on-iphone-with-zeppelin-beta/)) which allows the user replace the Carrier logo with any logo of their choosing.